# CSS styling not showing in browser (Chrome)

Tags: html, css

Fairly new to HTML/CSS and was doing a follow along project. My CSS styling doesn't carry over to Chrome when I want to see what I have so far. I can drop my code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Gritt-ify</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./resources/css/stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Banner section -->
    <div class="banner">
        <h1>Gritty's landing banner</h1>
        <img id="grimage" src ="./resources/images/gritty img.jpg" alt="">
        <p>Cause everything's better with Gritty's face on it</p>
        <button> Subscribe to Gritty</button>  
    </div>

    <!-- Gritter section-->
    <div>
        <span>Gritter</span>
        <p>Social media dedicated to Gritty and only Gritty</p> 
        <form action="">
            <input type="text"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div></div><span>Hey there, it's Gritty again.</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div></div><span>Hey there, it's Gritty again.</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div></div><span>Hey there, it's Gritty again.</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my minimal CSS so far:

```
.banner {
    background-color: #4D00FF;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 75px;
    text-align: center;
}

#grimage {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

If I made a fairly stupid mistake, feel free to shout it out. Thanks.

**EDIT: The problem's been resolved. Thanks to everyone who contributed!**

Comment: Is the CSS file shown in developer tools (Sources)?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./resources/css/stylesheet.css"> try revalidating your path

Comment: remove the `.` in your `link` tag

Comment: The stylesheet.css carries over, however the code from within stylesheet does not.

Comment: Do a Ctrl+F5 (Hard Refresh). And still if no output is given. Open the inspector in chrome go to the networks part and reload the page again. See if the css is getting loaded or is it 404. If 404 change the css page link in the html head

Comment: Copy and paste from an answer: Apologies if I've misunderstood anyone's directions. For what it's worth the stylesheet file carries over to Chrome, but the code within it doesn't. I've gone into inspect -> sources -> resources folder -> css folder -> stylesheet.css but the code within stylesheet.css isn't there. My css only works when I copy it from vs code and paste it directly into the source in dev tools. Again, fairly new to all of this, I appreciate everyone's time and input on this topic helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `.` prefix from your links, this applies to your `head` section and the image you are using.

Replace

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./resources/css/stylesheet.css">`

With

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/stylesheet.css">`

Comment: Hi Tobi, thanks for the answer but I've tried the prescribed code and the css styling still isn't showing up. Apologies if I've misunderstood anyone's directions. For what it's worth the stylesheet file carries over to Chrome, but the code within it doesn't. I've gone into inspect -> sources -> resources folder -> css folder -> stylesheet.css but the code within stylesheet.css isn't there. My css only works when I copy it from vs code and paste it directly into the source in dev tools. Again, fairly new to all of this, I appreciate everyone's time and input on this topic helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

You have one folder per se. In this example, let's just call it "Christian INDEX". Inside that folder, you have your index.html and a folder called "styles" *like so:*

[image]

Now, inside the styles folder, you have your "stylesheet.css". The browser has to grab the CSS from one folder back from the current (index.html) to grab the style sheet in the styles folder. Now because it only has to go back once you can use `.styles/stylesheet.css`

If you had a folder called index and had the index.html inside that folder then you would use two `..`

File structure that works:

```
~Christian INDEX (parent ~ main folder)
 -styles (folder) 
       ~ stylesheet.css [file]
 -index.html [file]
```